# Optimal representation of a contiguous range

Tags: algorithm, range

I have some unsigned int type of (say) k bits, which can store the values 0 up to but not including N (= 2<sup>k</sup>). Using two such uints, I would like to represent any contiguous range of those values, where a range is conceptually an offset and a length, and empty ranges with different offsets are considered distinct. For example, I want to be able to represent any subrange of `[0, 255]` using two uint8s.

One natural representation is a tuple `(offset, count)`. However this can't represent the full range of `[0, N-1]` because then the count would need to be N.  Another representation is the half-open interval `[start, end)`, but this cannot represent a range containing N-1, since the end is not included.

But two uints is enough, and here's a proof. We have two uints, each uint can represent N values, together they can represent N<sup>2</sup> values. There are N ranges of length 1, N-1 ranges of length 2, etc, down to 1 range of length N. We also have N ranges of length 0. Summing, we have `N*(N+1)/2 + N` total ranges. This can be rewritten as `N*(N/2 + 3/2)`, which is less than N<sup>2</sup> when N > 3. So two uints gives us more representable values than there are ranges.

So what is the most natural (i.e. convenient) way to represent ranges using two uints, that doesn't have any unrepresentable "holes"?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Do you really need to represent a subrange of 0? If not, then your representation of 1 item starting at offset 5 could be `(5, 0)`. And the representation of 255 items starting at offset 0 is `(0, 255)`. Basically, the `count` is actually `count-1`.

Answer (score 3):

The following works, though the last clause isn't the most natural:

1)  `[a,b]` for ordinary subintervals of `[0,1,...2^(N-1)]` where `a <= b`

2)  `[a, a-1]` for the empty interval starting at `a`, for `a > 0`

3)  `[2^(N-1), 0]` for the empty interval starting at `0`

The key point is that when you look at a tuple `(a,b)` you do the comparison `a<=b`. If that evaluates to true you interpret the tuple as giving the endpoints of a closed interval. If it is false then you interpret it as an empty interval. There is obviously a certain amount of flexibility in exactly how you code the empty subintervals, so points 2 and 3 can be tweaked easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Any representation is going to have some unnatural-ness, since there are N+1 ranges starting at 0, and since the representation can't generalize to N<=2. That said, we can try to minimize the special cases.

If we base our representation on `(base, number of elements)`, then we have a natural representation for every range except `[0, N-1]`. We can choose any unused tuple to represent this range, such as `(N-1, N-1)`, which for N>2 is not already the representation of some other range.

If we base our representation on `(first element, last element)`, we have a natural representation for all non-empty ranges. Unfortunately, we have N more empty ranges to encode, and representations like `(N-1, base)` only encode N-1 empty ranges, since `(N-1, N-1)` is already used. We end up needing two forms of special-case representation.

If we base our representation on `(first element, last element + 1)`, we have a natural representation for all ranges that don't end at N-1. Unfortunately, we end up needing two forms of special-case representation again, since it's hard to fit all 256 remaining ranges into one form of representation.

---

`(base, number of elements)` with `[0, N-1]` represented as a special case seems the most natural.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get mathematical, you could encode the ranges in a triangular number with base N. In this case we need all of the bits to represent the higher numbers. JavaScript example:

```js
function f(n,N){
  var a = Math.floor((Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * n) - 1) / 2);
  var b = n - a * (a + 1) / 2;
  return [N - a, N - b];
}
```

Output:

```
for (var j=0; j<15; j++){
  console.log(f(j,5));
}

/*
5,5
4,5
4,4
3,5
3,4
3,3
2,5
2,4
2,3
2,2
1,5
1,4
1,3
1,2
1,1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most natural way is to use inclusive ranges, i.e. (a,b) for all x | a <= x <=b.

If I really need to store a zero-length range then (1,0)

I've never encountered a situation in real life where I've actually had to distinguish the zero-length ranges.

This representation lets you write a reasonably nice loop without using a wider type:

```
for (uint i = range.start; i <= range.end; )
{
    ...
    if (!++i)
       break;
}
```