# Encoding a monomial [lx,ly,lz] to contiguous index and decoding back

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want help or guidance to write one procedure called `encode` to compute `index` as in the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int encode(int lx, int ly, int lz) {
          return (ly+lz)*(ly+lz+3)/2 - ly;
        }


int main() {
  int L;
  // Replace with your desired value of L 
  for (L = 0; L <= 5; ++L) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++) {
      int lx = L - i;
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++, index++) {
        int ly = i - j;
        int lz = j;
        std::cout << "[" << lx << "," << ly << "," << lz << "] ->" << index <<" vs " << encode(lx, ly, lz)<< std::endl;
      }

    }
    std::cout << "-----------" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

'encode` above seems to work. I would like to implement a procedure named decode that calculates lx, ly, and lz based on the given index. Both encode and decode procedures are expected to be called frequently, making their performance crucial. Therefore, any suggestions to enhance their speed would be greatly appreciated.

As requested, I will describe how `endode` works.

The given procedure, `encode(int lx, int ly, int lz)`, takes three non-negative integers `lx`, `ly`, and `lz` as input. These values represent a monomial `(lx, ly, lz)`.

The procedure calculates an index value based on the monomial `(lx, ly, lz)`. The index represents the index to store the information associated with the monomial in a contiguous array. The rules that follows the monomials are as follows:

1. The sum of the components `lx`, `ly`, and `lz` must be equal to `L`.
2. The value of `L` can take integer values from 0 to `N`, inclusive.
3. `lx`, `ly`, and `lz` must be non-negative integers.
4. `L` must also be a non-negative integer.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Edit the question to describe how the encode function works and what constraints on `lx`, `ly`, and `lz` there may be. Give context for the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While perhaps a good general rule, the code here is largely agnostic. The only differentiator is the `std::cout`. Otherwise, it can be answered by either tag as the solution code will pretty much be the same. If it were me, I'd remove the `c++` tag as `printf` would be fine here and I'm not sure there's a `std::` solution here. More eyes on the problem, IMO.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Yes, and if they want a general algorithm, they should not tag C or C++. The first approach to the code would be an abstract algorithm. After that, if they have a good algorithm, they could ask about implementing it in a specific language. For the former, they should not burden the people following the C or C++ tags and not following relevant other tags for asking about the abstract algorithm. For the latter, they should tag only one language.

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563523/enumerate-all-k-partitions-of-1d-array-with-n-elements)

Comment: @EricPostpischil How can `Enumerate all k-partitions of 1d array with N elements? ` be related to monomials? I cannot see how that question will help to solve this one.

Comment: @user3116936: Your code shows that that, for each L, you are iterating through monomials of three variables with total degree L. This is equivalent to partitioning the number L into a sum of three non-negative integers, a, b, and c, so a+b+c = L. That is equivalent to partitioning an array of L elements into three subarrays with a, b, and c elements, so a+b+c = L. Mathematically, they are the same problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is similar, but I don't think it is equivalent because in my case there are (L+1)*(L+2)/2 monomials for a given value of L.

Comment: @user3116936: And how many ways do you think there are to partition an array of L elements into 3 subarrays? There are two borders between three subarrays, and the first border can go before the first element, between any pair of elements, or after the last element, which is L+1 positions. The second border can go anywhere at or after the first border, up to just after the last element. That forms a triangular pattern (first border at 0, second at any of L+1 positions or first border at 1, second at any of L positions, first at 2, second at any of L−1, and so on), giving (L+1)(L+2)/2 results.

Comment: Your `encode` function can be replaced by `return (ly+lz)*(ly+lz+3)/2 - ly;`, yielding identical results. If you do not mind reordering the results, it could be simplified further.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Updating the code accordingly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I rather to keep the order of the monomials as much as possible. If changing the order allows for `endoce` and `decoode` functionalities, I will consider changing the order of the monomials and manage the impact of it differently.

Comment: [Also related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643474/optimal-representation-of-a-contiguous-range/33657609#33657609) There is a near-solution for `decode` in there.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I agree. However, I don't understand how to adapt it to decode  properly (lx,ly,lz) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initial Solution

As noted in the comments, the `encode` function can be replaced by `return (ly+lz)*(ly+lz+3)/2 - ly;`. This arises out of the fact that the encoding essentially follows triangular numbers: When we list the encodings in the desired index order, the list starts with one item with the maximum first *lx* value (*L*), and continues with two items with the next lower *lx* value (*L*−1), then three items with the next lower value and so on. So the number of items preceding the start of the current first index is the *n*<sup>th</sup> triangular number, *n*(*n*+1)/2, where *n* is *L*−*lx*. That gives us the encoding for the first triple with the given *lx* value. From there, we want to account for the *ly* values. These are also listed in descending order, so the first one is *L*−*lx*. As they descend, we want to add more to the encoding, so we add *L*−*lx*−*ly*.

That gives us (*L*−*lx*)(*L*−*lx*+1)/2+*L*−*lx*−*ly* = (*L*−*lx*)(*L*−*lx*)/2-*ly*. *L*−*lx* is of course *ly*+*lz*, so this is (*ly*+*lz*)(*ly*+*lz*+3)−*ly*, and hence `return (ly+lz)*(ly+lz+3)/2 - ly;`.

To reverse this, we recognize that, at the first list item with a given value for *lx*, the *L*−*lx*−*ly* contribution is zero, and we have the triangular number equaling the encoding *e*, so (*L*−*lx*)(*L*−*lx*+1)/2 = *e*. Solving this quadratic equation for *lx* gives *lx* = L + 1½ - sqrt(2¼ + 2*e*). (The quadratic has two solutions, but this is the one of interest to us, as the other would make *lx* greater than *L*.)

Thus, given an encoding *e*, we can set `lx = L + 1.5 - std::sqrt(2.25 + 2*e);`. This is exact when *e* is the encoding of the first list item for the given *lx*. When *e* is a later encoding for the same *lx* with different *ly* and *lz*, the formula gives a higher value, but it does not reach the next integer until *lx* changes. So the truncation to integer in the assignment yields the correct *lx* for all encodings with a given *lx* value.

I will leave the algebra for finding *ly* to the reader and give it as `ly = (L-lx)*(L-lx+3)/2 - e;`. And of course *lz* is merely `lz = L-lx-ly;`.

Thus a `decode` routine is:

```
#include <cmath>
void decode(int L, int e, int &lx, int &ly, int &lz)
{
    lx = L + 1.5 - std::sqrt(2.25 + 2*e);
    ly = (L-lx)*(L-lx+3)/2 - e;
    lz = L-lx-ly;
}
```

### Caution

The above requires that `sqrt` give a correct result when the result is exactly an integer. In C++ implementations where `sqrt` may deliver a poorly computed result, it may be necessary to make an adjustment, either by testing `lx` and incrementing if necessary or adding an adjustment, as with `L + 1.5 - std::sqrt(2.25 + 2*e) + 1e-10;`. A reasonable value for such an adjustment could be computed based on a bound on `L`.

Update: A nice way to do this is to subtract ½ from *e* in the calculation of `lx`. When 2¼+2*e* would be a perfect square, this moves it away from that (in the desired direction, making it smaller so subtracting it from *L*+1½ produces a large value, which will be truncated to the proper integer), which avoids bad consequences of small errors in `sqrt`, but it does not push other values of *e* across the next boundary where the calculated value of `lx` would change. And, since *e* appears as 2*e*, we can do this by subtracting 1 from 2¼+2*e*, thus using 1¼+2*e*: `lx = L + 1.5 - std::sqrt(1.25 + 2*e);`.